# joins a scoping model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I did't find doc about that.
I have two models, `Token` and `Connection`

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :token
  scope :failed, -> { where('...') }
end

class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
end
```

I know that we can join like this `Tokens.joins(:connections)` but I'm trying to do something like this `Token.joins(:connections => :failed)`
Do you think it's possible?

Comment: What to do you for `failed` to return?

Comment: @Pavan my failed condition just check many fields status

Comment: Write your *failed* `scope` properly! By putting  `where('...')` it is misleading that you are trying to create a `scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found

```
Token.joins(:connexions).merge(Connection.failed)
```

Comment: What is `not_failed`. Is it a scope? where you have written in the question?

Comment: wrong copy @Pavan, because in reality I have two scopes, one `failed` and the other `not_failed`

Answer (score 0):

you can add default scope on Connection model like

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :token
    default_scope where(' Your condition ')
end
```

so `Tokens.joins(:connections)` will give you only those tokens whose connections match your condition in scope.
you can check this link as well https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class